# nfs client reconnect after interface change

Tags: networking, mount, nfs

I have nfs client on my laptop which mounts couple of partitions over nfs from a local server.
Everything works fine, but I have problems when switching from wifi to utp interface and vice versa.
So, when I use utp and then plug it out and connect to the wifi network, the nfs partitions become inaccessible and also impossible to remount. When I issue mount command, it just hangs there.
If I reboot the laptop it mounts nfs without any problems.
I have no idea why the reboot is needed but it fixes it.
So, I'm looking for a way to do it without a reboot.

THanks

Answer (score 1):

First to solve problem with no possibility to remount partition.

Try with

```
umount -f -l /mnt/myfolder
```

that will fix the problem.

-f – Force unmount (in case of an unreachable NFS system).

-l – Lazy unmount. Detach the filesystem from the filesystem hierarchy now, and cleanup all references to the filesystem as soon as it is not busy anymore.

After successfully `umount` you will be able to mount again.

Now we can make some script to do auto remount based on network interface statu. You can use `/etc/network/if-up.d/` if you wont action when specific interface go up.

Make script called script with execute permissions 755

`sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/script`

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "wlan0" ] || exit 0
# Do something
sudo umount -f -l /mnt/myfolder
# then call your code to mounting `nfs`
sudo mount ...
```

This script will be executed when interface `wlan0` go up. Script will `umount` and after that `mount` your `nfs`
Also you can create script for `eth0` interface

`sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/script2`

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "eth0" ] || exit 0
# Do something
sudo umount -f -l /mnt/myfolder
# then call your code to mounting `nfs`
sudo mount ...
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your response. I managed to unmount with -f -l but when I try to mount it hangs....

Comment: one more thing, after some time it just becomes available, I guess something expires, but not sure what..

Comment: Only what I can suggest is to try after umounting do `sudo service nfs restart`, before mount command in script

Comment: Thank you very much for all your suggestions, it seems that nfs gets automagically remounted after some time, today I tried it 10 minutes after switching from eth to wifi and it worked without any intervention! I guess I can be patient that long and let it do it's thing :)